# How to manage relative paths from a single file?

Tags: php

How to manage relative paths in a project from a single file as its tedious to edit or update, I want to have a single file for it

```
       // Redirect to the home page if role is user else redirect to the admin dashboard
        if ($_SESSION['role'] === 'user') {
          header('location: ./../../index.php'); // this 
        } else {
          header('location: ./../../admin/index.php'); // this
        }
```

Manage path form Single file for whole project

Comment: you can easily define a constant or a variable to store the base path of your project!

Comment: The location header wants a URL, not a path in the file system